# SOAP PHP fails schema imports if types/particles are redefined

Tags: php, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I'm trying to connect on a external web service. But I'm getting the error

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: group 'http://xmlns.myWs.com/foo:MyGroup'
>   already defined

I've contact the webservice so they can fix the redefine error but I got the following answear

"We were able to reproduce your error using SOAP UI but we fixed when we disabled the option 'preferences>WSDL settings>fails schema imports if types/particles are redefined'. Please, disable this option on your programing language."

I really don't know how to disable this option in PHP. Anyone can helpt me? What should I do?

Note: I tryed to use wsdl2php but I got the same error

Comment: If anyone is having the same problem. SOAP-PHP only works in strict mode. So it's impossible to disable the option "fails schema imports if types/particles are redefined" like Soap Ui.
Unfortunately the webservice did not fixed the problem and we had to look for another partner with the same product.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to file.xml?singleWsdl instead of file.xml?wsdl